# What are the possible upgrades to a 95' Cannondale M900?

Tags: build, upgrades, cannondale

Everything is original except for saddle, tires and forks. I have a sentimental attachment to this bike but would like to bring it into the 21st century.  I'm looking to make this a nice project bike but don't know much about the compatibility of new components on this model. Things I would like to upgrade are; Suspension forks, wheel set and tires, disc brakes, front and rear chainrings, shifter/derailer, crank arms, handlebar and any other related parts needed. Looking to create a real retro beast.
The bike had the stock rigid forks that I upgraded myself to RockShox JudyXC back in the day but those elastomer pistons are toast. Since it's been a while that I traded serious riding for changing diapers I figure It's time to take the bike out of retirement and make it something worth riding and passing on to my son when he goes off to college in a couple of years. 
Any advice and/or guidance would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar era KHS Alite3000 - Most moving parts had been replaced from wear over its life, but pretty much original. AT 10.5kg, RockShox Judy's, XT components etc, it is a light, fast and agile bike. Like you, I gave up serious riding for kids, got back into it last year. The KHS, despite my fondness for the bike, has been given away in favor of a new bike. Like cars, bikes have moved a long way in 20 years, and the "practical" option is to replace it - especially if you ride off road.

The main reasons for me to replace rather than upgrade were cost exceeding the total cost of a new bike, no disk mounts and the old frame geometry not suitable for modern forks- back then 50mm was considered long travel, now 120 typical for XC.

If you really want to upgrade it, cheapest bet would probably be a "donor" bike. Getting decent forks with V brake bosses is next to impossible, so disks on the front would be easiest. Unless you got some second hand quality forks with V brake bosses.

What I would do is tune it up, replace any obviously worn out bits, and buy my son a new or 2-3 year old secondhand bike.

Answer (score 1):

There are alot of naysayers here who think it's not worth upgrading these older bikes. You have a really good quality bike and you should treat it as such!

However, you can't do everything to it. If there isn't a disc mount on the frame, then stick with rim brakes, but you can still upgrade the wheels.

A new drivetrain groupset (shifter/cranks&bb/derailleur/cassette/chain) can be bought as a package at a discount and fitted and takes the gear shifting into the modern era for not a huge outlay. You can even go 1x12.

The fork could be a problem and you can either decide to try and find a shorter travel replacement fork, get new elastomers fitted in the rockshox (it is possible to get elastomer replacements designed for another application though it's a struggle) or go back to a rigid fork on the basis that you might not be riding trails on this bike.

The money you put into it is irrelevant -- it will always feel better than a cheap new bike and be very much yours. You are doing this for your enjoyment, not to maximise resale value so your return on your investment is only the joy you get out of it. Enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar 1995 Cannondale M-900 in Vipper Red color version.  Some original parts have breen replaced but for original ones, trying to maintain muy bike in its optimal and original condition. I am proud of that and like very much to ride on my old but pretty M-900. To bring a very old bike onto a mew era is not only very expensive but thecnically almost impossibe. I recomend to buy a new one for your kid. 
Orlando

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're willing to buy all new componentry, so you have a lot of flexibility.

It doesn't look like there are many compatibility issues with it except the issue with disc brakes (rear wheel spacing is 135, front fork should be 1 1/8", Just get a new bottom bracket with your cranks).  I'd personally just put a disc in the front and then a good set of V-Brakes in the rear so you don't have to do some hack to retrofit discs in the rear.

After that, just grab a short travel front fork, a new wheelset, a 10 speed groupset with rapidfire shifters and should be pretty much up to modern spec for most parts.

Check out a vintage catalog for some original specs at
http://www.vintagecannondale.com/year/1995/1995.pdf

I love keeping vintage gear on the road.  You'll probably wind up putting more money in to this than a decent entry level bike though.

Comment: "You'll probably ....." - Understatement of the decade......

Comment: "just grab a short travel front fork, a new wheelset, a 10 speed groupset" - which (practically) means also a front disk setup. It's probably cheaper to buy a new bike as a donor....Whats left after that, frame, seat and handlebars......

Comment: I figured the OP wanted to do this stuff since he said "Things I would like to upgrade are; Suspension forks, wheel set and tires, disc brakes, front and rear chainrings, shifter/derailer, crank arms, handlebar and any other related parts needed"

Answer (score 0):

I got a Cannondale M900 from the early 1990's.  I daily ride it for my commute of a bit more than 300 miles per week, with usually at least one century ride.

I have replaced numerous chains, cassettes, front rings, put a rear rack on it with a convertible bag (with drop out paniers), run two sets of lights (batteries won't run short on me and I can get extra light), new rear rim, new tires (still running tubes), new saddle with a Cane Creek suspension seat post, new front fork (Fox with disc brake mount), new front rim, dyno 28 hub, Cinq Plug 5, new uprights on the end of the bars, front hydraulic brakes with a huge rotor and as many pistons as I could get.  Next on the list will be a Rohloff hub with a Gates drive.

In short, hell yes, you can get whatever you would like.  Yes, I could buy a new bike.  However, I got a top of the line aluminum frame now fitted out with high end gear for far less than a new with high end stuff.  Runs great, love spending time on it.

Good luck, enjoy your ride and ride on